# Solr Faceting count drop to zero

Tags: java, php, solr, faceted-search

The application I work on use Solr to index pages or products of different stores. When I say "products of different stores", it means that a product can be available in store A or store B, but not on store C. If a customer is connected to the store C website and search for a product that is not available in this store, it should not appear in the search result.

I have a "type" field in my schema that permitted me to tell if the document is a "page" or a "product". Now that I have this search constraint, this field contains either "page" or a composite key like this "productA" of "productB". You guessed it, A or B is the id of the store.

For each products in the DB, I will index it n times, where n is the number of available stores that sell this product.

I wanted to use faceting search in order to filter which store I wanted to search on, but I'm in front of a problem:

I'm beginning the indexation and search for "foobar" without faceting the search. I get a list of facets like this:

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="type">
        <int name="productA">10</int>
        <int>0</int>
</lst>
```

This number is growing and growing (which is normal) until the indexation of the store A is finished. 
Then I begin the indexation of store B and get this kind of result when querying solr

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="type">
        <int name="productA">303</int>
        <int name="productB">6</int>
        <int>0</int>
</lst>
```

but after a while, solr gets mad and send me this result:

```
<lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="type">
        <int name="productB">320</int>
</lst>
```

Yes. I don't even got my facet count for `productA` and I can't even search on it! It will bring 0 results.

Do you have an idea of what's going on?
Is using facet for this kind of problem is wrong?

Comment: You're probably overwriting documents by primary key. Can you get any productA documents?

Comment: No I can't get any productA documents. Thanks for your answer. It sounds SO obvious now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably overwriting documents by unique key. Make sure that the products from different stores have different unique keys. You could do this by appending a prefix per store to the unique key value.